# ipython non-linear least squares with constraints equations

Tags: scipy, least-squares

I am new to iPython, and need to solve a specific curve fitting problem, I have the concept but my programming knowledge is yet too limited. I have experimental data `(x, y)` to fit to an equation (curve fitting) with four coefficients `(a,b,c,d)`, I would like to fix one of these coefficients (e.g. a ) to a specific value and refit my experimental data (non-linear least squares). coefficients b, c and d are not independent of another, meaning they are related by a system of equations.

Is it more adequate to use `curve_fit` or `lmfit`?

**I started this with curve_fit:**

```
def fitfunc(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a+b*x+c/x+log10(x)*d
popt, fitcov = curve_fit(fitfunc, x, y)
```

**or a code like this with `lmfit`:**

```
import scipy as sp
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

def fctmin(params, x, y):
    a = params['a'].value
    b = params['b'].value
    c = params['c'].value
    d = params['d'].value

    model = a+b*x+c/x+d*np.log10(x)

    return model - y

#create parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value = -89)
params.add('b', value =b)
params.add('c', value = c)
params.add('d', value = d)

#fit leastsq model
result = minimize(fctmin, params, args=(x, y))

#calculate results
final = y +  result.residual
report_fit(params)
```

Comment: The key here seems to be that your coefficients are not independent. If they were, `curve_fit` should do the job just fine. But you don't seem to be handling the dependence in either of your solutions above, so there is no guarantee that the output from `curve_fit` or `lmfit` will preserve that dependence. Can you solve the dependence equations for one or more independent variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit to being biased.  curve_fit() is designed to simplify scipy.optimize.leastsq() by assuming that you are fitting y(x) data to a model for y(x, parameters), so the function you pass to curve_fit() is one that will calculate the model for the values to be fit.   lmfit is a bit more general and flexible in that your objective function has to return the array to be minimized in the least-squares sense, but your objective function has to return "model-data" instead of "model"

But, lmfit has features that appear to do exactly what you want:  fix one of the parameters in the model without having to rewrite the objective function.
That is, you could say

```
params.add('a', value = -89, vary=False)
```

and the parameter 'a' will stay fixed.   To do that with curve_fit() you have to rewrite your model function.

In addition, you say that b, c and d are related by equations, but don't give details.   With lmfit, you might be able to include these equations as constraints.   You have

```
params.add('b', value =b)
params.add('c', value = c)
params.add('d', value = d)
```

though I don't see a value for b.  Even assuming there is a value, this creates three independent variables with the same starting value.   You might mean "vary b, and force c and d to have the same value".  lmfit can do this with:

```
params.add('b', value = 10)
params.add('c', expr = 'b')
params.add('d', expr = 'c')
```

That will have one independent variable, and the value for c will be forced to the value of b (and d to c).  You can use (approximately) any valid python statement as a constraints constraint expression, for example:

```
params.add('b', value = 10)
params.add('c', expr = 'sqrt(b/10)')
params.add('d', expr = '1-c')
```

I think that might be the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: thank you!!! its exactly what I was looking for.  I also found out, that if I want to use the so calculated coefficients in a later equation, I need to use:                                                                    a = params['a'].value
    b = params['b'].value
    c = params['c'].value
    d = params['d'].value